# How do you write to Kafka using the ABRiS library in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

Has anyone been able to write to Kafka using [this](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS) library using PySpark?

I've been able to successfully read using the code from the README documentation:

```
import logging, traceback
import requests
from pyspark.sql import Column
from pyspark.sql.column import *

jvm_gateway = spark_context._gateway.jvm
abris_avro  = jvm_gateway.za.co.absa.abris.avro
naming_strategy = getattr(getattr(abris_avro.read.confluent.SchemaManager, "SchemaStorageNamingStrategies$"), "MODULE$").TOPIC_NAME()        

schema_registry_config_dict = {"schema.registry.url": schema_registry_url,
                               "schema.registry.topic": topic,
                               "value.schema.id": "latest",
                               "value.schema.naming.strategy": naming_strategy}

conf_map = getattr(getattr(jvm_gateway.scala.collection.immutable.Map, "EmptyMap$"), "MODULE$")
    for k, v in schema_registry_config_dict.items():
        conf_map = getattr(conf_map, "$plus")(jvm_gateway.scala.Tuple2(k, v))
        
    deserialized_df = data_frame.select(Column(abris_avro.functions.from_confluent_avro(data_frame._jdf.col("value"), conf_map))
                      .alias("data")).select("data.*")
```

However, I am struggling to extend the behaviour by writing to topics via the `to_confluent_avro` function.